# Logon Failure: unknown user name or bad password Error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a website on `\\WEBSERVER` that needs to download from two UNC virtual dir: `\\vDir1` and `\\vDir2` from two separate pages.

`\\WEBSERVER` to `\\vDir1`:

- No problems
- same `user`/`password` on both computers
- Connect as... with `user`/`password` on IIS 7
- Test Settings... gives green in authentication and authorization, "Path is accessible"

`\\WEBSERVER` to `\\vDir2`:

- Logon Failure: unknown user name or bad password when trying to browse `\\vDir2`
- same `user`/`password` on both computers
- Connect as... with `user`/`password` on IIS 7
- Test Settings... gives green in authentication and authorization, "Path is accessible"

So in all, I have three servers all with the same user account `user`/`password`. I pass the credentials through the application pool's identity which is the only app pool that runs for this website.

I am still learning IIS, but I am thinking my problem lies within the computer of `vDir2`. I've even added `user` to "Access this computer from the network" in Local Security Policy but still no luck.

PS: The webpage uses form authentication so I do not want to enable anonymous authentication.

PSS: in Visual Studios, `vDir1` has a web.config file automatically written when I disable anon authentication. `vDir2` threw an error and did not write a web.config file when disabling anon authen. Enabled write permissions, still threw same error.

Please help

Comment: Where do you see "Logon Failure: unknown user name or bad password when trying to browse "? While you are running the web application? I guess all three servers are on a domain? Is `user` a domain account or a local account? What is the app pool identity set to?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, I see the error whenever I try to access the vdir from iis, when I attempt to download the file from the web application it gives an unhandled exception - System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'D:\\XXXX.xlsm' I am certain the path is correct, when copy+pasting into file explorer, there is no problem finding it (the physical that is). The `user` account is a local account on all three servers, and the app pool identity is set to `user`. Again, the first vdir has no problem downloading when using `user` but the second one is a different story...